# Migration problems from local wordpress to a server

Tags: wordpress

I've recently started using Wordpress for a school project, and since i already had a google cloud account from before, i decided to host my site there. I created it locally and designed it, to see if it would work, but now i am trying to migrate it to the google cloud server. I export my database, then import it into the server. Now when i did this at first Wordpress told me i had already installed it (correct), then threw me into a blank page. After searching around for a bit i found [this](https://devanswers.co/find-replace-urls-wordpress-database/), right here on Stack Overflow and it made sense to me. So i ran the commands, replacing all instances of *localhost* with *serverIP*.

Now the reason i am asking this question is because the above procedure didn't fix my problem. It correctly redirects *serverIP* to *serverIP/siteName*, but it gives me a 404 error. I am wondering, if i did something wrong, and how i could fix it?

Thank you for the answers in advance.

Edit: Detail i forgot to add, though i don't think it matters: my local computer (where i originally hosted wp) runs Windows 10, while the google cloud server runs Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but it may be the solution to your problem. I will describe another way how to get your wordpress page from your localhost development to your webhost.

1. Install wordpress on your webhost as it is with the newest version from wordpress.org
2. Finish the install progress, so wordpress sets up all database tables for you and all is empty (except the hello world post and the data privacy page).
3. Go to your localhost wordpress backend and install under tools the wordpress export plugin to export all your data in your website. The result is an xml file. But you can also use a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/
4. Copy your complete wp-content folder from your localhost wordpress page via ftp into your wordpress installation on the webhost. you can first delete it and than put the folder from the localhost in.
5. Go to your freshly installed wordpress page, activate all your now appearing plugins (if you have some) and under tools in the backend, use the wordpress importer to load all your data in the new database (may take a few minutes). You can also use a plugin like all in one wp migration.
6. The plugin you postet is to overwrite the urls in your database. This is useful, if you change the base url of your wordpress site. If you followed the steps, you should actually don't have to do it. But you can, if want to be double sure or have some data with the urls in your database.

Hope this makes your deploy more easy.

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer did indeed help me! While the manual transfer of wp-content didn't work, using the all in one migration did a great job. I knew there were some migration plugins but i didn't know such a simple one existed!